# ffmpeg library rotates video after compression Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm using **ffmpeg** library for video file compression in my Android project.

To implement ffmpeg I refereed [this link.](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) Compression is working fine but after compression process this library rotating my video 90 degree which I don't want to be happen. I googled a lot but yet not reach to solution which can tell me how to stop rotating the video. For video compression I'm using the following command--

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -strict experimental -vf transpose=1 -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -b 2097k /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information to you.

Thank you.

Comment: The `-vf transpose=1` is rotating the video. Remove it.

Comment: @Mulvya Yes.. 
0 = 90CounterCLockwise and Vertical Flip (default)
1 = 90Clockwise
2 = 90CounterClockwise
3 = 90Clockwise and Vertical Flip

Comment: So, did you add the filter to correct the rotation?

Comment: I tried all above option mentioned in my comment but not working.

Comment: Did you add the filter?

Comment: No. Actually I don't know how to add filter, can you plz guide me..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command has a transpose filter in it which will rotate the video. You can simply remove it.

```
ffmpeg -y -i /sdcard/videokit/in.mp4 -b:v 2097k -s 160x120 -r 30 -aspect 4:3 -ab 48000 -ac 2 -ar 22050 -strict experimental /sdcard/videokit/out.mp4
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but after removing transpose filter my app is getting crashed. My Log is---   A/libc(18472): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000018 (code=1), thread 18647 (AsyncTask #5)
W/PhoneWindow(18830):

W/DefaultRequestDirector(18830): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {token=WWW-Authenticate: Token}

Comment: Looks like either an old version or not suitably compiled. Try a different build.

Comment: Great... this solution worked for me.. I just removed "-vf transpose=1" parameter from my command. Thanks @Mulvya..